# I get "bad file descriptor" error when i try to run pip commands

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, package

When i try to run any pip or anaconda command i get this error. I ve tried reinstalling python.

***i am using python 3.8.5***

```
    from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\compat.py", line 64, in <module>
    from http.cookies import Morsel
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 859, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 917, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

**here i ve tried to install pygame using pip**

Comment: I believe it may have something to do with your operating system. Try reinstalling Python.

Comment: thanks but i get the same error

Comment: Try changing the install location in the installer options to some other directory or a different drive.